# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todas las fechas y horas de un año?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener todas las fechas-horas de un año teniendo en cuenta los cambios de hora de marzo y octubre?

```
2019-01-01 01:00
2019-01-01 02:00
....
....
2019-12-31 23:00
```

Estoy intentándolo con la clase Calendar pero no obtengo resultados satisfactorios.

Comment: ¿qué quieres decir con "teniendo en cuenta los cambios de hora"? Es decir, ¿qué salida esperas para esa fecha y hora?

Comment: ¿Qué forma intentaste tú con Calendar? Incluye el código en tu pregunta, por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero, decir que eso de los cambios de hora de marzo y octubre es algo que depende de la zona horaria a la que te refieras. Supondré que hablas de la zona horaria española peninsular.

Si quieres que la hora salte de la 01:00 a las 03:00 el día de marzo en que se adelanta el reloj, o que se repitan las 02:00 el día de octubre en que el reloj se atrasa, la forma más simple que se me ocurre (y no es para nada simple) es trabajar con la clase `datetime` que sea "consciente" de la zona horaria.

Aunque la biblioteca estándar `datetime` viene preparada para ello, sin embargo no trae definiciones para todas las zonas horarias del mundo, o sobre las fechas concretas en que se produce el cambio horario, dejando esa labor bien al usuario o bien a otras librerías de terceros, que deben implementar esta funcionalidad en una clase apropiada que herede de `tzinfo` (que es una clase abstracta que debe ser implementada apropiadamente para las diferentes zonas horarias).

La librería `pytz` es una implementación de todo esto.

Haciendo uso de `pytz` definiríamos cuál es la zona horaria para Europa/Madrid, y la zona horaria UTC (que es universal y no sabe de cambios de hora). Usaríamos un bucle para ir generando las fechas/horas en UTC, pero a la hora de imprimirlas las convertiríamos a la zona horaria de Europa/Madrid, y así observaríamos el comportamiento deseado.

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

# Zona horaria
madrid = timezone('Europe/Madrid')

# Formato en que queremos mostrar la fecha/hora
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

# Crear las horas de inicio y fin en UTC, y un intervalo de 1h para incrementos
inicio = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=utc)
fin = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 23, 0, tzinfo=utc)
_1h = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

# Generar la lista de horas
t = inicio
lista_de_horas = []
while t<fin:
  # Observa cómo se convierte de UTC a Madrid, y luego a cadena con el formato deseado
  lista_de_horas.append(t.astimezone(madrid).strftime(fmt))
  t+=_1h
```

El resultado lo tienes en la lista `lista_de_horas`. Si observamos las partes "delicadas", vemos que se comporta como querías (si no te entendí mal):

```
>>> lista_de_horas[2132:2140]
['2019-03-30 21:00',
 '2019-03-30 22:00',
 '2019-03-30 23:00',
 '2019-03-31 00:00',
 '2019-03-31 01:00',
 '2019-03-31 03:00',
 '2019-03-31 04:00',
 '2019-03-31 05:00']

>>> lista_de_horas[7172:7180]
['2019-10-26 22:00',
 '2019-10-26 23:00',
 '2019-10-27 00:00',
 '2019-10-27 01:00',
 '2019-10-27 02:00',
 '2019-10-27 02:00',
 '2019-10-27 03:00',
 '2019-10-27 04:00']
```

## Usando Pandas

Otra opción es usar Pandas. No te aconsejaría instalarlo si es solo para esto, pero quizás ya lo tengas instalado o incluso lo estés usando en tu problema, por lo que esta solución podría ser más simple en ese caso:

```
import pandas as pd
lista = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01 00:00", 
                      end="2019-12-31 23:00", 
                      tz="Europe/Madrid", 
                      freq="H" )
```

En este caso la lista que obtienes no es una verdadera lista, sino un objeto `DatetimeIndex`, y sus elementos no son cadenas, sino de objetos `datetime` "conscientes" de la zona. Estos objetos por defecto se imprimen en una forma que no es la que buscas, pues incluyen también los segundos y el offset con respecto a UTC. Mira, por ejemplo:

```
>>> lista[2132:2140]
DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-30 20:00:00+01:00', 
               '2019-03-30 21:00:00+01:00',
               '2019-03-30 22:00:00+01:00', 
               '2019-03-30 23:00:00+01:00',
               '2019-03-31 00:00:00+01:00', 
               '2019-03-31 01:00:00+01:00',
               '2019-03-31 03:00:00+02:00', 
               '2019-03-31 04:00:00+02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Madrid]', freq='H')
```

Pero siempre puedes convertirlos a otra cadena usando el formato que quieras, por ejemplo:

```
>>> for h in lista[2132:2140]:
...   print(h.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

2019-03-30 20:00
2019-03-30 21:00
2019-03-30 22:00
2019-03-30 23:00
2019-03-31 00:00
2019-03-31 01:00
2019-03-31 03:00
2019-03-31 04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución que encuentro para tu problema es que des un rango de fechas como en el codigo siguiente y asi coloque el rango de fechas de un año para que te imprima en pantalla

```
import datetime
fechai = '2019-05-22'
fechaf = '2019-06-22'
inicio = datetime.datetime.strptime(fechai, '%Y-%m-%d')
final = datetime.datetime.strptime(fechaf, '%Y-%m-%d')
aux = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while inicio <= final:
     print inicio.date()
     inicio += aux
```

Usa la libreria datetime para las fechas la variable fechai es la fecha inicial y la variable fechaf la fecha final.

las variables inicio y final son las que toman los valores de ingresos los convierten en formato fecha